# Save .csv file in the same directory as .py file

Tags: python, csv

I am tring to save my .csv file which is a result of some queries in the same location as the .py file.

```
import os
with open(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))+'MyCSVFile.csv','wb') as output_file:
    dict_writer = csv.DictWriter(output_file, keys)
    dict_writer.writeheader()
    dict_writer.writerows(myList)
```

I always seem to get my csv file one directory before. When I print os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)) it gives me the proper path but the output MyCSVFile is saved one above. What is the problem here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use os.path.join to save the csv file in the same directory

```
import os

dirname = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
csvfilename = os.path.join(dirname, 'MyCSVFile.csv')

with open(csvfilename, 'wb') as output_file:
    dict_writer = csv.DictWriter(output_file, keys)
    dict_writer.writeheader()
    dict_writer.writerows(myList)
```

This should work as excepted

Answer (score 1):

Remove the call to `os.path.dirname` since you are already calling `os.path.abspath`. Calling `dirname` returns the directory component thus you are getting the directory up in the hierarchy. BTW: use `os.path.join` to join parts of a directory.